# Is there a way to check if Mapillary user name exists with API v4?

Tags: api

I need a query to check if Mapillary profile with some username exists. I founded out that it could be done with this query on API v3.

https://a.mapillary.com/v3/users?usernames=%s&client_id=%s

Here is [example on Java](https://github.com/osmandapp/OsmAnd/blob/d2114dce418fa9a0f070f32d8c4f5ef4f815dfa7/OsmAnd/src/net/osmand/plus/mapillary/MapillaryAutoCompleteAdapter.java#L164)

But now this query is irrelevant. I also read [Mapillary API v4 documentation](https://www.mapillary.com/developer/api-documentation), but did't find what I needed.